# How to deal with a package "not upgraded" using aptitude?

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude

I'm (still) on Debian Squeeze. When I try to upgrade the system, here's what I get:

```
[09:20]/root# aptitude upgrade
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Looking at the log, I get a hint at the name of the culprit package:

```
Aptitude 0.6.3: log report
Sat, Jun 22 2013 09:20:13 +0200

IMPORTANT: this log only lists intended actions; actions which fail due to
dpkg problems may not be completed.

Will install 0 packages, and remove 0 packages.
===============================================================================
[HOLD] libxcb1
===============================================================================

Log complete.
```

However, if I look at the package, I don't get any more details:

```
[09:21]/root# aptitude show libxcb1
Package: libxcb1
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 1.6-1
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Maintainer: XCB Developers <xcb@lists.freedesktop.org>
Uncompressed Size: 188 k
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.2), libxau6, libxdmcp6
Breaks: libxcb-xlib0
...
```

I'm surprised by how little info `aptitude` is giving me about its refusal to upgrade the package.

My question is: **What are the steps I should follow in this situation to find out why this package is not upgraded?**

---

**Update**: Here's the desired command:

```
$ apt-cache policy libxcb1
libxcb1:
  Installed: 1.6-1
  Candidate: 1.6-1+squeeze1
  Version table:
     1.6-1+squeeze1 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.6-1 0
        500 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Can it be that your `sources.list` still points to the squeeze repos?

Comment: Yes it does. I haven't moved to Wheezy yet. Is it relevant?

Comment: Run `apt-cache policy libxcb1` and paste the output. I think aptitude respects apt pinning. You could also try running `apt-get install libxcbi` and see what happens.

Comment: @rahmu of course it is! When you run `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get` compares the state of the packages on your system against the state of the packages in your chosen repo. See my answer below.

Comment: Use `apt-get dist-upgrade` is an immediate, yet radical solution to your problem. I actually post to quote: "In case of doubt, please use the apt-get and apt-cache commands over the aptitude command." [http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_literal_apt_get_literal_literal_apt_cache_literal_vs_literal_aptitude_literal]

Comment: The `apt-cache policy` looks normal. Did you try `apt-get install libxcbi`? If that doesn't work, check that there is no aptitude hold on the package, though this won't happen unless you do it yourself. I think aptitude can do its own holding/pinning. Also, do you have anything in `/etc/apt/preferences`? BTW, if you want to notify someone, you need to use the @ symbol. I just happened to see this question again.

Comment: Also note that the apt utilities `apt-get` and `apt-cache` are actively maintained and probably more used by people in general than `aptitude` these days. Aptitude's original maintainer is no longer active, and while there is currently work by Daniel Hartwig and others to continue maintenance, for the present `apt-get` and `apt-cache` should be considered the go-to defaults.

Answer (score 4):

You need to know why aptitude doesn't want to install that version of the package, with a quick `why-not` you can figure this out:

```
aptitude why-not libxcb1=1.6-1+squeeze1
```

But my guess is that one of the 79 reverse dependencies depended of the 1.6-1 version of the package, since there isn't any packages that breaks/conflicts with this library.